# custom iterator for vector<struct>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, iterator

Suppose I have a `struct` like this :

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    string b;
    //....
};
```

and I have a vector of this `struct` :

```
   vector<S> vect(100);
```

I want to have `random_access iterator` that points to all of `vect` int's member(a in this case) 
How can I implement it ?

Comment: What you need to implement is described at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator Have you tried?  Where's your code?  Where did you get stuck?  (It should be pretty much like writing an iterator for all of S, except on dereference you'll return a [`const`] reference to `a` alone.

Comment: If Boost library is an option, consider transform_iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant way could be the operator* overloading, direcly inside struct:

```
struct S {
    int a;
    string b;
    inline int operator*() const {
      return a;
    }
};
```

In this way, when you iterate S elements in vector, you can access to 'a' in this easy way:

```
std::vector<S*> vect(100);
std::vector<S*>::iterator it = vect.begin();
for(; it != vect.end(); ++it) {
   std::cout << **it;
}
```

with:

- *it: you access element pointer by iterator
- **it: access element a thanks to the overloading

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap a `std::vector<S>::iterator`. All operators can be forwarded directly except `operator*` which of course has to return `S::a`

Comment: And `operator->`, and "of course has to return S::a" *by reference*.

Comment: @TonyD: Even `operator*` has to, since `*it = 5` has to be legal too.